# Translation: Street-Smarts/Street Smart?

Tags: translation

How to translate street smart into Mandarin?

Baidu gives:

> n.     城市生活方式、生存能力

but that's can't be right...

As in:
`A street smart cop.`

or

`A cop with street-smarts.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally it means empirical wisdom gleaned from the streets.

市井聪明, 街市里积累的智慧

市井 [street]∶街市,
    [urban vulgar class]  指城市中流俗之人

Source: http://baike.baidu.com/view/849797.htm

聪明【英译】wise；sensitive clever；smart

Source: http://baike.baidu.com/subview/95047/11119951.htm

Comment: I think just "市井" works as well.

Answer (score 1):

老江湖(neutral)

or

老油条(somehow negative)、老浆糊(somehow negative)

Answer (score 0):

iciba has １ example sentence with 他有都市人的精明劲儿，web search yields http://www.unsv.com/voanews/words-and-idioms/lessons/152/ Lesson 152 - street smart （two-way street）.
Note that VOA流行美国习惯用语 Lesson １５２
concerns the noun ＂street smart(s)＂，there also is Lesson ２０ http://www.unsv.com/voanews/popular-american/lessons/20/ for the adjective which seems to indicate that the VOA people were not aware of a simple precise Chinese analog。

Answer (score 0):

It seems that no exact word for it, we can say he is a 百事通。

Answer (score 0):

小聪明
that would work coz this is the closet expression
市井聪明 could work but it's more of a written style while my answer could used basically everywhere

Comment: 小聪明 is rather negative and would be better translated as 'smart ass' than 'street smart'...

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking maybe 能幹 or 經驗老道 has some similar meaning to it.

能幹: capable, useful.

經驗老道: have abundant experiences.

Answer (score 0):

In Cantonese there's a saying called:

世界仔

meaning: a person that has street smart, excellent at social skill and dealing with people